# How to Click on webelement issue

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a page that can have several datepickers on a page.

I run the first loop find out how many datepickers the are.

```
        List<WebElement> calanders = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".c-input-group__addon"));  
        for(int i1=0; i1<calanders.size(); i1++) {      
        System.out.println("how many calanders " +i1);
        }
```

I then loop through the datepicker and click on the required date.

I then need to click on a button to close the picker to continue, this is where i am having an issue.

`calanders.get(1).findElements(By.xpath("//label[contains(@class,'c-option')]")).click;`

How can i click on the second occurence of `By.xpath("//label[contains(@class,'c-option')]` ??

```
    List<WebElement> calanders1 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".c-input-group__addon"));  
    for(int i1=1; i1<calanders1.size(); i1++) {         

    driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".c-input-group__addon"));

     calanders1.get(i1).findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(@class,'c-option')]")).click();

    }
```

Comment: Use '.' in front of the xpath - By.xpath(".//label[contains(@class,'c-option')]"). This will make sure you are searching for the close button inside the calendar to be closed.

Comment: Without the relevant `HTML` (and a snap of the `Date Picker` along with `Close` button) it will be tough to guess what we need to do to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to find via F12 how many elements are on the page by your xpath.
   Maybe it couldn't click because there are more elements than 1 by your locator.
2. You could add waiter until element is clickable. 
   Or just add Thread.sleep() but it isn't good practice.

p.s. It is better to print exception log to your question